# How to save data in Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, core-data

I created an entity named House. This entity has two attributes which are street (of type string) and numOfStories (of type integer 32). I was able to successfully save and NSLog data in my AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. However, when I try to make 2 textfields and show the User's input, and make a button to save, the result is SIGABRT.

[image: a busy cat]

Here is all the code I'm using in my MainViewController.m:

```
- (BOOL)createNewHouseWithStreet:(NSString *)paramStreet numOfStories:  (NSUInteger)paramNumOfStories
{
BOOL result = NO;

if ([paramStreet length] == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Street name is mandatory");
    return NO;
}

House *newHouse = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"House" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];


if (newHouse == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to create the new House");
    return NO;
}

newHouse.street = paramStreet;
newHouse.numOfStories = @(paramNumOfStories);

NSError *savingError = nil;

if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&savingError])
{
    return YES;
}

else
{
    NSLog(@"Failed the save the new House. Error = %@", savingError);
}

return result;
```

}

and below this I have

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {



[self createNewHouseWithStreet:@"10 WYOMING" numOfStories:2];
[self createNewHouseWithStreet:@"6 WYOMING" numOfStories:3];


NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"House"];

NSError *requestError = nil;

NSArray *houses = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&requestError];

if ([houses count] > 0)
{
    NSUInteger counter = 1;

    for (House *thisHouse in houses)
    {
        NSLog(@"House %lu Street Name = %@", (unsigned long)counter, thisHouse.street);
        NSLog(@"House %lu number of stories = %ld", (unsigned long)counter, (unsigned long)[thisHouse.numOfStories unsignedIntegerValue]);
        counter++;

    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Could not find any House entities in the context.");
}
```

}

So what's weird is that this code ends up resulting in sigabrt whenever I tap the save button, but when I put the code from the save method into my AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method it works great.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If the code works elsewhere, then the button must be the problem. What's the full text of the error message?

Comment: When I NSLog anything in the save button it works fine. But this is the error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'House''

Comment: It seems as though If I put anything core data related into that button such as  House *newHouse = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"House" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
I still get SIGABRT

Comment: self.managedObjectContext seems to return nil. Where do you initialize it?